# What is the correct syntax for this situation?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I am confused with JS. I wrote a pseudo-implementation of a Stack, which is saved in its own file. I want to "Create" a Stack object in a separate file, however, WebStorm is telling me of a syntax error. See error below:

```
import Stack from "./Stack"
       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Here is how I'm calling the import in the tester file, based on the recent suggestions from other users:

```
// Stack.js
class Stack {
    ....
}
export default Stack

// StackTester.js driver file
import Stack from "./Stack"
    ....
```

Comment: Are you writing JS for front-end (web) or backend (node.js) environment?

Comment: @Xiangyu.Wu I don't know how to answer that correctly. I am currently a beginner in JS.

Comment: @sudherrsingh No. I am currently using this line: export class Stack {

Comment: Do you expect to run your code in a web browser or in a console (command line)?

Comment: @Xiangyu.Wu just in the console sir.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your version of node.js. The `import` syntax is supported (as a **experimental** feature) in node.js 8.5.0+ . In order to use this feature, you need to:

1. If you use an old version of Node.js, you need to upgrade it.

   Your node.js interpreter used by WebStorm can be found in `Setting` -> `Language & Frameworks` -> `Node.js and NPM`, you might found the version based on the directory path (e.g. in my case it is 8.12.0), or based on command similar to `node -v`

   [image]
2. Rename all of your `*.js` files to `*.mjs`. e.g. Rename `stack.js` to `stack.mjs`
3. Run your `mjs` file with `--experimental-modules` command line parameter. If you use command line, you should use something similar to `node --experimental-modules main.mjs`. If you use webstorm, you can config it through webstorm command line parameter (as shown in the screenshot)

   [image]
   [image]

However, `import`/`export` statements are not the best way to do modular development in node.js. It is mainly use in front-end web development with webpack. Usually in node.js, we use `require` and `module.export`, it should be something similar to

```
// In stack.js
class Stack {

}
module.export = {Stack}

// In main.js
const {Stack} = require('./stack.js')
```

Also, you may need to enable the ES6 syntax in Webstorm if it shows warning message in editor.

`Setting` -> `Language & Frameworks` -> `JavaScript`, in the dropdown of `JavaScript Language Version`, select `ECMAScript 6`.

[image]

Comment: The current version I have installed is 12.3.0

Comment: @binibiningtinamoran I missed something in the previous answer, maybe you can have a try in the update version...

Comment: @binibiningtinamoran Can you show me the latest version of your `stack.mjs`?

Comment: I added the .mjs extension on the line `import Stack from "./Stack.mjs";` and it works. But I'm still confused with importing modules/files.

Comment: To be simple, we use `module.export`/`require` for node.js (as shown in my answer), and use `import`/`export` in web development (with webpack)

Answer (score 0):

In Stack.js, are you exporting as default ie.:

```
function Stack() {
  // some code
}

export default Stack  // <== check if word "default" used here
```

Then when you import, you don't need to destructure (use curly braces), the import should just be

```
import Stack from './Stack".
```

Comment: I edited my post. I included some lines from both the Stack and StackTester files.

Comment: add the word default after your export (ie. export default class Stack {} ), and then your import should work (ie. import Stack from "./Stack")

Comment: I did what you suggested but it is still throwing a syntax error `import Stack from "./Stack"
       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: @Xiangyu.Wu's advice specific to WebStorm may be your answer. Also, just to confirm, is Stack.js is in the same folder/directory as your code ?

Comment: Stack file is in the same folder as the calling driver file.